# Java sudoku Solver Method

Tags: java

I'm trying out this code for a project where we do the fill grid and evaluate methods for a given sudoku grid via three urls that we can interchange within the code. I'm not interested in efficiency at this point because I'm still trying to get a handle on Java. So far this is the code I have for the evaluate method

I understand the logic behind the first two for loops for the box but I'm trying to understand the second two

EDIT: I'm asking if I what I wrote for the box checker is correct because it still returns false even though the written grids are all correct sudoku boards

```
public boolean evaluate() {
// check row
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < 9; k++) {
            if (gridButton[i][j].getText().equals(gridButton[i][k].getText())) return false;
        }
    }
}
// check box
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i += 3) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j += 3) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
                if (gridButton[i][j].getText().equals(gridButton[k][l].getText())) return false;
                k += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
// check col
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        for (int k = i + 1; k < 9; k++) {
            if (gridButton[i][j].getText().equals(gridButton[k][j].getText())) return false;
        }
    }
}
return false;
}
```

I worked with my professor for a viable row checker and I adapted it myself for the col checker but I'm still not totally sure about how to write the box checker.

Comment: So... you're asking **us** to explain how **your** code work? ...

Comment: @selbie, how exactly does your comment add to the understanding of OP, it's basically self-advertising. It might be understandable if the code was actually written in java though. Otherwise, there are thousands, if not millions of code submissions concerning Sudoku. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome to reference my C++ code for solving a Sudoku board [here](https://github.com/jselbie/SudokuSolver)

Comment: @KrishnanshuGupta - I didn't mean to come across as self-aggrandizing.  Looking back, I can see how my original could be construed as such. But I do believe I am uniquely qualified to answer questions about Sudoku algorithms given *that I have published a working solution intended for others to reference*.  In the case of the OP, he's rather vague, but  now that I've studied his question I think I can answer....

Comment: Side note for the op: you are comparing strings via `=` operator. Using `.equals()` will be more reliable.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mean to doubt your capabilities of answering the question, with that many reputation points and past programs, I don't think anyone has that right. I just meant to say that something in Java, would have been more helpful to the op. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Box algorithm in your code does 9x9x3x3 == 729 comparisons.

Perhaps a better approach would be to use a HashSet across each row, column, or box.  Once a duplicate value is found in the set, it can bail out.

With using a Set, there's `9x3x3 == 81` looksup and insertions to be made. Assumption is that Set insertion and lookup are both **O(1)**

```
// check box
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {  // for each major 3x3 box

    set.clear();               // start with an empty "set"

    // examine each cell in the box. If the cell's value is already in
    // "set", then we have a duplicate and should exit. Otherwise, add
    // the cell's value to the set
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
            int row = (i / 3) + r;
            int column = 3*(i%3) + c;
            String val = gridButton[row][column].getText(); 
            if (set.contains(val) {
               return false;   // the value of the cell was already found, bail
            }
            set.add(val);      // not found, add it to the set
        }
    }   
}
```

You can apply the same technique to the "check row" and "check column" algorithm and have less comparisons to make as well.  That's an exercise I'll leave up to you to solve.

And if we were comparing integers instead of text strings, we could use a simple Boolean array instead of a HashSet instance.  :)

Comment: I'm wondering, is Hash's computation speed actually O(1) or does it just get close to it, because nothing can be O(1) right? Please, do correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Hash table insertion/lookup time is `O(1)` in best case. `O(N)` in worse case when each item hashes to the same bucket. And yes, you can get to absolute O(1) for a fixed number of items (e.g. integers 1-9) and a corresponding number of buckets to match.  Looks a lot like an array of booleans.